# Python dataframe filtering based on date comparison

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp

> I am trying to filter my dataframe using date. The date imported from the csv is in string. hence I created a new column with the date in the 'Timestamp' format. Then I wanted to compare with a particulare date, however I am getting the following error

- TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'list' and
  'Timestamp'

**Here is my code**

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['agent_1','2019-06-27 15:35:49'],['agent_2','2029-06-27 15:35:49'],['agent_3','2019-04-27 15:35:49'],['agent_4','2029-06-27 15:35:49'],['agent_5','2019-02-27 15:35:49']]
MasterData = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Agents','timeCreated'])
MasterData['timeCreatedUpdated'] = pd.to_datetime(MasterData['timeCreated'],format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
MasterData.dtypes
datetime_object2 = pd.Timestamp(2019,8,1,12)
MasterData(['timeCreatedUpdated']>datetime_object2)
```

Comment: The error is clear enough; square brackets define `list` in Python: https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/datastructures.html. You are comparing a list with a timestamp. This makes no sense.

Comment: I think that in R this is valid, maybe that's why the confusion

Answer (score 0):

The last line needs to be edited:

```
MasterData[MasterData['timeCreatedUpdated']>datetime_object2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Mondy - you did everything right just a small correction in last line

Use

```
MasterData[MasterData["timeCreatedUpdated"] > datetime_object2]
```

instead of

```
MasterData(['timeCreatedUpdated']>datetime_object2)
```

It does the main comparison for you and returns a Boolean (True/ False), now we wrap the answer again in DF to get values.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
print(MasterData[MasterData['timeCreatedUpdated'] >pd.Timestamp(2019,8,1,12)])
```